# how to make a java program ide free

Tags: java, netbeans

So I made this Java code project in NetBeans for a very un-computer savvy friend, and It runs fool proof, I even took the time to GUI it, but I want this to be as simplistic as possible where she can simply load the project off of a flash drive and just double click the file and it will run independently of Netbeans or any other IDE's. Is there a way to do this, I think a better way of explaining what I am looking for is how can I make my code compile and run through the program alone. Kind of like Chrome would when you double click it, it would just open up and start going to work. Hopefully there is some kind of setting in NetBeans that will do this automatically.

Thank you for any and all help/comments

Comment: Welcome to SO, please make sure to include examples in your questions, this question is to broad, so people will not be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Package the program in an executable JAR file.

See: [Lesson: Packaging Programs in JAR Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) in Oracle's Java Tutorials for information on how to do this.

For how to do this from NetBeans, see: [Packaging and Deploying Desktop Java Applications](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html) on the NetBeans website.

Your friend will have to have Java installed, then (s)he can just double-click the JAR file to run your program.